# AngularJS not loading

Tags: angularjs

1. HTML code as below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ng-cribs</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller = "cribsController">
  <h1>{{ hello }}</h1>
 </body>
 

 

</html>
```

02.app.js file

```
angular.module('ngCribs',['ui.boostrap']);
```

03.cribsController.js file

```
 angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('cribsController', function($scope){
        $scope.hello = 'Hellow world';
    });
```

Problem

index file loads as `{{ hello }}` instead Hellow world

Answer (score -1):

You may need to inject `$scope` into your controller like this:

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('cribsController', ["$scope", function($scope){
        $scope.hello = 'Hellow world';
    }]);
```